# Object hierarchy using std::list from libc++ (bug?)

Tags: xcode, list, stl, libc++

I think I found a bug in the libc++ list implementation. The following code will produce a compiler error (Field has incomlete type 'foo') when using certain build settings in xcode:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class foo {
    public:
        list<foo> bar;
};
```

The settings are the following:

**XCode Version:** 4.4.1
**C++ Language Dialect:** C++11 or GNU++11
**C++ Standard library:** LLVM C++ standard library with C++ extensions (libc++11)

Using GCCs libstdc++ will resolve the error.
Not using the C++11 dialect will resolve the error.
Using vector instead of list will resolve the error.

I think it is a bug in the list implementation, but I am not sure.
Forgive my ignorance, but I don't know what I should do to resolve this issue.
Switching to vector is not an option in my project and I definitely need C++11 features. That also includes shared_ptr, but the headers are missing when using GCC. Beside that, apple does not seem to provide new versions of GCC anymore.

I would very appreciate it if somebody could recreate this issue, maybe with newer header from libc++.

Also, if updating LLVM/libc++ would resolve this issue, do you recommend it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ Standard 17.6.4.8:

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - ...
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component,
>   unless specifically allowed for that component.

None of the standard library's container class templates, including `list`, mention any such allowance for an incomplete type.  So your program is an invalid one that might happen to work with some compilers.  That can't be considered a bug in the standard library implementation.